# How to use a JCombobox in JMenu?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu

I want to add a Combobox to my JMenu but its not working properly. When I click it the menu closes.

I tried to add a JMenuItem and a JPanel with the combobox to the menu but neither worked.

```
public class Combo extends JMenuBar{

    public Combo(){
        this.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setBorder(null);
        this.add(createCombobox());
    }

    

    private JMenu createCombobox() {
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("test");
        JLabel box = new JLabel("Color");
        String[] colors = {"blue", "green", "yellow"};

        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(colors);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 5, 0, 0, Color.DARK_GRAY));
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panel.add(box, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.EAST);

        menu.add(panel);

        return menu;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That seems some what like an anti pattern to me - why not make it a sub menu instead?

Comment: You have not put any size constraints on your vomponents. I think a JPopupMenu would be more what you want. Note, when you click a menu it is "used" , it would then disappear. You could however programmatically put "focus" into the combo box, but you would need also to instruct the user to use arrow keys to change the selection and manage events on another button press such as return button and keyup. I'm not sure how much you can get by default from the GUI .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea seems like an anti pattern to me - it doesn't really make sense when you consider that you could use a sub menu to effectively get the same workflow in a more expected and user acceptable way.

*(There's also a million or more technical issues why I wouldn't even try and use a `JCombobox` this way, but lets stick with the fact that there is a pre-existing acceptable UX workflow)*

Take a look at [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) and [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for some more details.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away...", 10, 30);

        public TestPane() {
            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu menu = new JMenu("Text");
            menuBar.add(menu);

            JMenu color = new JMenu("Color");
            menu.add(color);

            ColorAction.Observer observer = new ColorAction.Observer() {
                @Override
                public void didSetColor(ColorAction action, Color color) {
                    textArea.setForeground(color);
                }
            };

            color.add(new ColorAction("Blue", Color.BLUE, observer));
            color.add(new ColorAction("Green", Color.GREEN, observer));
            color.add(new ColorAction("Yellow", Color.YELLOW, observer));

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
        }
    }

    public class ColorAction extends AbstractAction {
        private static Observer Observer;

        public interface Observer {
            public void didSetColor(ColorAction action, Color color);
        }

        private Color color;
        private Observer observer;

        public ColorAction(String text, Color color, Observer observer) {
            super(text);
            this.color = color;
            this.observer = observer;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (observer == null) {
                return;
            }
            observer.didSetColor(this, getColor());
        }
    }
}
```